# How do I suppress specific keystrokes in Linux so xev does not recognize them, but the Python keyboard module does?

Tags: python, linux

I'm trying to suppress the input of Linux keyboard inputs **temporarily** for **specific** buttons, while still being able to read the input using the Python *keyboard module* (`keyboard.read_key()`) and *subprocess module*.

Simply removing the entire keyboard with terminal command '`xinput --set-prop keyboard_id Device Enabled 0`'
disables all keyboard inputs and terminal command '`xev`' no longer recognizes these inputs. However, the Python keyboard module can still read the keys. This is what I want, however, for specific keys only.

Using `xmodmap ~/.Xmod_custom`, I created a custom keymap called *.Xmod_custom* in which which I remapped the keys to what is supposed to be nothing (simplified code with the R key mapped to nothing):

[...]

```
keycode  27 =
```

[...]

However, `xev` still recognizes this keycode when I press the R key.

How would I be able to hide keyboard input from `xev`, while still being able to listen to it?